# Validate Request against OpenAPI YAML in Python

Tags: python, validation, swagger, schema, openapi

I have written API documentation using Open API 3 standards (using [stoplight.io](https://stoplight.io)). Now I'm implementing the API in Python 3.7, and I don't want to rewrite all of the schemas, not to mention I'd like my API to be coupled with my documentation to prevent discrepancies.

I've found tools like [pydantic](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/) and [openapi-schema-validator](https://pypi.org/project/openapi-schema-validator/) that seem relevant, but don't fit my use case. For example, pydantic wants me to create the pythonic objects first and then export to `json_schema` and `openapi-schema-validator` wants just the json schema while I have an Open API yaml.

This seems like a standard question, but I haven't found a good answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use [openapi-core](https://github.com/p1c2u/openapi-core) or [connexion](https://github.com/spec-first/connexion) which both support request and response validation..